# 404 file not found on believed correct path?

Tags: html, path, gulp

I have a simple Angular application that I am bundling with Gulp. The index.html has a script reference of:

`<script src="./../../js/all.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

and a file structure:

[image: file structure]

Does this not seem accurately relative?

I am also serving from the public/html/layout/index.html

Comment: Can you try to change `./` to `../`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<script src="../../js/all.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: The file is still 404ing

Comment: Have you tried <script src="../js/all.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: No, because it is two directories deep

Answer (score 0):

The resolution involved a best practice of placing the index.html at a higher level directory. Still didn't explain why the issue occurred, but the issue is no longer affecting me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Chrome then you can open your index.html in the browser and goto View Source.

Find this line in the source: `<script src="./../../js/all.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`
and **click the hyperlink** of the file. It will then show you the **complete address of the javascript file the browser is trying to load**. Once you get the complete address I believe you can fix this issue easily.
[image]